# Slim routes with question marks and 404

Tags: routes, slim

I'm using Slim for my project and I have some issues with the routes.

I'm trying to access to: /user/login/facebook?go=go

But I always get a **404 error**.

I've tried with these routes:

```
$app->get('/user/login/facebook?', function(){

$app->get('/user/login/facebook/?', function(){

$app->get('/user/login/facebook', function(){

$app->get('/user/login/facebook/', function(){
```

This is my **.htaccess**:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?path=$1
```

Any idea how to solve this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite rules suggested by [Slim documentation](http://docs.slimframework.com/#Route-URL-Rewriting) works for me.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```